# Follow up post - How can I query SVN repository or database?

Tags: database, svn

This is a follow up to an old question - [How can I query my subversion repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569865/how-can-i-query-my-subversion-repository)

I am using Polarion SVN web client to see the SVN revisions for a particular app in trunk. So, it looks like SVN has some kind of database where it probably stores a commit and related info. I want to get this info directly, without using the polarion tool. Reason - It looks like Polarion does not allow me to get TOP 1 Revision <= Given revision number because I don't see any filters for that. I want to get this info directly from svn DB. Is this possible ? Is it advisable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be much better off NOT re-inventing the interface to an SVN repository. Even if you could figure it out, there is no guarantee the database format would not change, breaking your tool, at the next SVN upgrade. On the other hand, the command-line interface and probably various programming APIs will continue working just fine after the upgrade. If Polarion is too limiting, try using the command-line interface, or some other interface, but don't try writing your own client. There's too much work to do that, with hardly any gain, and you risk it breaking every time you upgrade your SVN repository server.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I'll have to learn SVN commandline then.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please give me + 1 ? Someone just downvoted me for no reason.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that sort of voting is frowned upon. I'm not going to start trying to do reputation manipulation even for good reasons.